# how to call clear method on the element object

Tags: ruby, watir

In my project I have located the text_Field via some other element(via label), something like

```
element.following_sibling(tag_name: 'input').send_keys 'something'
```

But now it's typing into the text_field without any problem but I am missing clear method of `text_field` as it combines both clear and type together. Now I have to call clear method on `element.following_sibling(tag_name: 'input')` but since it's returning element object, I couldn't do that. Is there any way I can call clear method here? Or can I pass this object by some way to the text_field() method? Any help appreciated.

I know it can be called by converting the watir element into selenium element as given below

```
element.following_sibling(tag_name: 'input').wd.clear
```

But here I am missing WATIR waiting time for an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a limitation in Watir's [adjacent methods](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/a04669517c79ce6d02df3d7e31a9f8b87bb8752d/lib/watir/adjacent.rb#L116-L124):

```
  klass = if !plural && opt[:tag_name]
            Watir.element_class_for(opt[:tag_name])
          elsif !plural
            HTMLElement
          elsif opt[:tag_name]
            Object.const_get("#{Watir.element_class_for(opt[:tag_name])}Collection")
          else
            HTMLElementCollection
          end
```

Notice that only the `:tag_name` is used for determining the element's class. For input elements, we need to also consider the type attribute so that we can the right sub-class.

We should fix this in Watir (logged as [Issue 878](https://github.com/watir/watir/issues/878)), but in the mean time, you can manually correct the class (ie `Watir::TextField`) using `#to_subtype`:

```
element.following_sibling(tag_name: 'input').to_subtype.clear
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer to my question now.

Here is the answer.

```
b.text_field(element: element.following_sibling(tag_name: 'input').wd).set 'something'
```

If anybody has any better idea, please write your answer.Thanks.